# Xamarin Forms TapGestureRecognizer Is not issuing command

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, xamarin.android

So I have a xamarin forms app that currently only implemented for android. I am attempting to implement a tap event. When tapped though this never hits the command in the ViewModel. I'm not sure if I have something the matter with my code or I am just implementing it wrong.

ViewModel Code:

```
    private RelayCommand<object> _OnClickableLabel;

    public RelayCommand<object> OnClickableLabel
    {
        get { return _OnClickableLabel ?? (_OnClickableLabel = new RelayCommand<object>((currentObject) => Test(currentObject))); }
    }

    private void Test(object currentObject)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "were going down cap", "OK");
    }
```

Page Xaml:

```
  <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}" RowHeight="100">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnClickableLabel }" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Label FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                    <Label FontSize="Small" Text="{Binding Text}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I have tested it using a method in the page's cs code and that works fine but it has to be implemented in the ViewModel because it affects that data.

Comment: your command is on the base VM, but the `BindingContext` of **each row** in the `ListView` is an individual `Notification` object, not the entire VM.  You can get around this by using a [relative binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings)

Comment: Did not know about that, pretty new to Xamarin. I assume I use the AncestorType version of relativeSource? Where do I figure out what type is supposed to be in AncestorType? Putting the ViewModel there doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Another work around might be to give your page a name, like `x:Name="this"`, then set the source on the binding, something like: `Command="{Binding OnClickableLabel, Source={x:Reference this} }"`

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you want to [add a tap gesture recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap) in ListView, and want to pass ListView current row data to TapGestureRecognizer event, am I right?

If yes, as Jason's opinion, you need to take a look [Xamarin.Forms Relative Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) firstly,name ListView as listview1, then take a look the following code:

```
<ListView
            x:Name="listview1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}"
            RowHeight="100">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.OnClickableLabel, Source={x:Reference listview1}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Label FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                            <Label FontSize="Small" Text="{Binding Text}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

public partial class Page16 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Notclass> Notifications { get; set; }
    public ICommand OnClickableLabel { get; set; }
    public Page16()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Notifications = new ObservableCollection<Notclass>()
        {
            new Notclass(){Title="title 1",Text="notification 1"},
            new Notclass(){Title="title 2",Text="notification 2"},
            new Notclass(){Title="title 3",Text="notification 3"},
            new Notclass(){Title="title 4",Text="notification 4"},
            new Notclass(){Title="title 5",Text="notification 5"}

        };
        OnClickableLabel = new Command(n=> {
            var vm = (Notclass)n;
            Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert",vm.Title , "OK"); 
        });

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}

public class Notclass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; } = Color.White;
}
```